# Trying to manage and run a web server

Tags: server, software-installation, software-center, lamp

I'm fairly new to ubuntu server, although I have played around with it a bit in the past. I'm trying to build and manage the server but I keep running into problems. Examples: software center not working correctly, blank screen when accessing localhost/template_name/install, terminal giving errors messages "All The Time" (I'm just going to stop using the terminal completely).

All I need is Lamp install and working correctly and a few other third party software alongside it. Is there an easier way of working with lamp and installing software other than the terminal?

Comment: You can *not* manage a server without the command line.

Comment: The only way we can help is if you provide exactly what error messages the Terminal gives.

Comment: I've already deleted the OS and I'm reinstalling it now. Are there any libraries for the terminal that would possiably help? Or programs/files that could help make managing everything easier?

Answer (score 0):

Try webmin control panel for GUI management of the whole system such as web server and also package installation